# UWP MapControl: Center map around more than one point

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a MapControl in my UWP C# app to which I have added some markers at certain coordinates. Now I want to zoom and adjust the map view so that all the markers can be seen on the same view, i.e. so that I don't have to zoom out or adjust the map center manually.

So, what I have is a list of points:

```
List<Geopoint> points;
```

now how do I get the correct map zoom and center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UWP Map control has a method to be sure certain points are in the visible area.
It's called `TrySetViewBoundsAsync` docs can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.trysetviewboundsasync

You use it like this

```
await ActivityMap.TrySetViewBoundsAsync(GeoboundingBox.TryCompute(geopositions), null, MapAnimationKind.None);
```

So the class `GeoboundingBox` can be used with the `TryCompute` method to get the actual GeoboundingBox, docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation.geoboundingbox.trycompute